# ELK Ubuntu Server - Kibana login page not showing

Tags: elastic-stack, elk

I have installed ELK on ubuntu 22.04. ELasticseacrh, logstash and kibana was installed properly and kibana UI was opened.

But When i setup security for elastic search using below link :-

[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/security-basic-setup.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

It was done properly and got below message on output on running this command (`curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://167.99.121.86:9200/_cluster/health?pretty`)

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 1,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

And done changes in kibana configuration as specified in above link. I got below error message in kibana log file :-

```
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.6.1"},"@timestamp":"2024-01-02T18:45:19.102+00:00","message":"Kibana process configured with roles: [background_tasks, ui]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"node"},"process":{"pid":352245},"trace":{"id":"1be97f1adf94644e00cd43fab6ad76db"},"transaction":{"id":"faefe9135cad9fb4"}}
```

{

Can someone please guide me on this

Display Kibana login page